# negative wp_postmeta number

Tags: database, wordpress, meta

I have a large database in a dev site (a result of rss syndication) and now I am having trouble with it.  I'm deleting lots of posts, but when I check my database in mysql I see a wp_postmeta number of -179,433.  This can't be right...  What could be the cause of this kind of value?  Additionally, I am having trouble deleting the posts out of the trash.